# How do I upload an iterative pre-commit patch to Crucible (svn)?

Tags: svn, pre-commit

our team uses Subversion as a source code repository and Crucible (2.10) for code reviews. We'd like to follow pre-commit code review approach using patches. However we found it's impossible to do iterative reviews, since every new patch creates separately, preventing us from viewing diffs between them. I read docs, researched it on this forum and web, however couldn't find an answer. The closest I found was: [How do I upload an iterative pre-commit patch to Crucible?](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/11989164) , however they use Mercurial, which is different from SVN and doesn't work for us. Please assist here.

Comment: Has your team considered working on branches, and reviewing the branches prior to merge, rather than reviewing every commit before it happens? You can delete the branch after the review closes if you want, and have basically the same end result. And then you encourage, rather than discourage, frequent small commits and frequent updates.

Comment: @Ben , branch would be a good choice, however we don't follow this approach. There's an article on Crucible web-site how to do iterative pre-commit reviews: confluence.atlassian.com/crucible/…. However, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved by updating to a newer version. Iterative pre-commit reviews magically appeared.